# how to set first day of month as default in date prompt in Cognos

Tags: javascript, html, date, prompt, cognos

I am trying to create date prompts as beginning and ending date. Default value will be first day of month and the ending will be yesterday. I find the way to reach yesterday with javascript in the code below yet I could not set the first day of month in default selection in Cognos. Do you know how to do that, thank you so much.

```
<script language="javascript">
var dDate = new Date();
//Subtract one day
dDate.setDate(dDate.getDate()-1);
pickerControlDate_P.setValue(getFormatDate(dDate, 0 , 'YMD'));
</script>
```

Comment: let firstDate=new Date(dDate.getFullYear(),dDate.getMonth(),1);

Is it what you need?

Comment: You need a bit more logic than that. If today is say 1 Dec, then the start will be 1 Dec and the end will be 30 Nov.

Comment: What version of Cognos?

Comment: Cognos has a fair bit of prompt supporting built in. Here is an example.  You can specify the data type as one of the parameters of the prompt macro.


[Business View].[time].[DAY_DATE]  
between  
_first_of_month((#prompt('The month of this date')# ))
 and 
_last_of_month ( (#prompt('The month of this date')# ))

Comment: What's your goal?  Do you need to set the default values for a prompt, then allow the user to change the value before running the report?  Or do you need to set the parameter values as described when the report is run?